# Trouble with MySQL query using AVG()

Tags: php, mysql, average

I am using a query that takes an average of all the records for each given id...

```
$query = "SELECT bline_id, AVG(flow) as flowavg 
          FROM blf 
          WHERE bline_id BETWEEN 1 AND 30 
          GROUP BY bline_id 
          ORDER BY bline_id ASC";
```

These records are each updated once daily.  I would like to use only the 10 most recent records for each id in my average.

Any help would be qreatly appreciated.

blf table structure is:

```
id | bline_id | flow | date
```

Comment: so you want to use `LIMIT 10`?

Comment: +1 You'll also need to order descending by your date to get "most recent records for each id in my average."

Comment: LIMIT 10 just lets you display the average results for 10 id's such as 30-21 when viewed DESC or 1-11 when ASC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to simulate ROW_NUMBER().

This statement creates a counter and resets it every time it encounters a new bline_id. It then filters out any records that aren't in the first 10 rows.

```
SELECT bline_id, 
       Avg(flow) avg 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               bline_id, 
               flow, 
               date, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN @previous IS NULL 
                       OR @previous = bline_id THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := 1 
               end rn, 
               @previous := bline_id 
        FROM   blf, 
               (SELECT @rownum := 0, 
                       @previous := NULL) t 
        WHERE bline_id > 0 and bline_id < 31
        ORDER  BY bline_id, 
                  date DESC, 
                  id) t 
WHERE  rn < 11
GROUP  BY bline_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b55c/23)

It's worthwhile seeing this in action by removing the group by and looking at [intermediate results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b55c/24)

Comment: Very nice. I will give it a try tomorrow!

Comment: That works excellent as well. I will run both examples and compare for a while. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user2039676 your welcome. I think Gordon's first one is the right way to go though since you have the nice *each updated once daily*. However not everyone is so fortunate.

Comment: Actually I forgot that it is not updated on weekends so the first version never submits a total of 10 records because it doesn't see 10 consecutive dates. Gordon's second option, and yours return identical results :)

Comment: I do not want to impose on your generosity of helping me solve this problem, but judging from your reputation you may be the right person to point me in the direction of achieving the next step of my goal for this project! Up for a challenge?

Answer (score 1):

If these are really updated every day, then use date arithmetic:

```
SELECT bline_id, AVG(flow) as flowavg
FROM blf
WHERE bline_id BETWEEN 1 AND 30 and
      date >= date_sub(now(), interval 10 day)
GROUP BY bline_id
ORDER BY bline_id ASC
```

Otherwise, you have to put in a counter, which you can do with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT bline_id, AVG(flow) as flowavg
FROM (select blf.*,
             (select COUNT(*) from blf blf2 where blf2.bline_id = blf.bline_id and blf2.date >= blf.date
             ) seqnum
      from blf
     ) blf
WHERE bline_id BETWEEN 1 AND 30 and
      seqnum <= 10
GROUP BY bline_id
ORDER BY bline_id ASC
```

Comment: First option sounds like what I want but does not return anything?

Comment: @user2039676 . . . somehow the word `select` crept into the query in the wrong place.

Comment: @user2039676 . . . The date method is simpler and more understandable.  The other method is less efficient.  I would go with the date method, but be inclined to include `count(*)` in the `select` list to see how many dates were actually chosen.

Comment: I will give that a try. Thanks a million! Next I have to figure out how to account for a +- 2% change in the value when it's updated each day!

Comment: @GordonLinoff [turns out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622791/trouble-with-mysql-query-using-avg/15623875?1#comment22193791_15623875) weekends introduce a problem. Think it's possible to deal with that for the first query? I guess the big problem there is dealing with `NOW()` being a saturday or sunday.

Comment: @ConradFrix . . . It requires changing the limits on the `between` so `30` would depend on the day of the week.  It sounds like you want 22 days of weekday history.  That would be 30 days on a wed, thu, or fri; 33 days on a Tuesday and 34 days on a Monday, if my off-the-cuff calculations are right.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not the OP. I was referring to the comments on my answer. Also I don't think it's the `bline_ID` clause but the `date_sub` clause. I'm thinking it would be `date >= date_sub(now()  CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(NOW()) = 7 THEN 14 WHEN WEEKDAY(NOW()) = 6 THEN 13 ELSE 12 END day)` although I've not tested a case statement in date_sub