# SQL - how to reuse unsigned field values that have been deleted

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Firstly, I am very new to SQL so I am having trouble explaining what my problem is. Any issues with what I am asking and I will clear it up.

I am having trouble with my database in SQL where I am using phpmyadmin. I have an unsigned field, and When I add a room to a room table it gives it a `room_id` value of `1`. This then incrementally goes up as I add rooms. This make sense. But if I have two rooms `(id 1, 2)` and I delete no.2., then I add another room, the next room id will be id 3. Is there a way to make sure that it takes the next available slot rather than continuously incrementing? i.e. if I deleted room 2 the next room created would take an id of 2?

I am VERY new to SQL and so please hold my hand and guide me through what I need to do rather than giving me an overcomplicated answer...please!

Comment: *Is there a way to make sure that it takes the next available slot rather than continuously incrementing?* This is quite complicated to do *correctly*, largely due the the concurrent nature of databases. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Because I'm as bad at coding as I am at SQL. In short. But I will try to explain in more detail give me a second to think about what my problem is and how to explain it.

Comment: Ok so basically I was iterating through the rooms by using a variable such as room++ then using that to do sql statements as my next room. But since I have a room 1, and then a room 20, it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm thinking I might need to use another for loop to iterate through the array?

Comment: Yes this solved the issue

Comment: Another option you might want to explore is assigning the room number in your SQL. [Here's an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9939b/5) This technique is useful in [N per group scenarios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622791/trouble-with-mysql-query-using-avg/15623875#15623875)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your ID field is set to be auto increment. And this is how it works, it stores the max number id in the table and then increments it and assigns it to the next inserted row.

Think about it, say you have the next rows: row_1 (1), row_2 (2), row_3 (3). If you delete row_2 row, the next row index would be 4, so you will have something like this: row_1 (1), row_3 (3), row_4 (4).

If you want to put you own logic in the id field, you should unchecked the A_I option and in each insert put any number as you want (**while it stays unique**).

Answer (score 1):

Your table has an primary key that is arbitrarily assigned by the database.  Its purpose is to insure that each record in the table can be uniquely identified.  The fact that there are gaps in the numbers, caused when individual records are deleted, is no cause for concern and should be ignored.

Subsequent `INSERT`s into the table will not re-use those deleted primary key values, nor should they.

If the issue here is that you're using that value to determine the number of records in the table, then instead of that, use a query such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [tablename]
```